# What is the need of deploying an application to servers like AWS and Heroku? can't we deploy on normal Systems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, web-deployment

I want to deploy a small ROR application. i come across AWS and Heroku hosting servers. As i am new to these deployments, i have a dought like why people prefer deploying to these(AWS, Heroku etc.,) servers ? we can buy a high end hardware system with high configuration and we can ensure the power and internet supply 24/7 and deploy application to this System. What is the Advantage that people will get, which is making them to choose these paid infrastructure?

Comment: The advantage is not having to worry about provisioning hardware. What if an hdd dies in your high-end server? What if the whole box dies from lightning strike/flood/earthquake/hurricane? What if you thought you can ensure power/internet 24/7 but something went wrong and you have an outage? etc, etc. With aws all these are not a concern, at all.

Comment: also doing the `system administration` of the server would be an additional time consuming work, as **economies of scale** applies, big provider like *Heroku* or *AWS* have competent *system engineers* managing the security and administrating your server for free for the basic services, but they can also provide scalable servers and consulting/support services per payment.

Comment: Right now `Heroku` is having some issues and all my apps are down, I can not restart `dynos` and the issue is with heroku. The `dyno` crashed and I can not restart them, but I am ok with it. I believe you are experiencing the same too if you deployed to heroku. https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1334